# CSS Triangle Positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically what I want is a CSS Triangle that is vertically aligned in the center of my content, positioned at the right of my content with a slight padding without using explicit measurements based on the triangle's `border-width`.

The wrapper should expand to contain the CSS Triangle if the triangle is huge like in this example and the CSS Triangle should always be vertically aligned in the middle of the wrapper.  If there is a large amount of text, the CSS Triangle should just overlap the text if they cross.

This seems perfectly reasonable, but I ran into some problems; check out this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QuwEc/2/) for where I'm at now.

If I assign a `min-height`, I can get to `1.` below.  The problem with `1.` is that I have to choose an arbitrary height.  Moreover, if content grows, it won't be perfectly vertically centered because of the `top: 25%` which doesn't truly put it in the middle.  To allow multiple different sizes of arrows easily, I really don't want to assign a min-height or any height for that matter, I just want it to calculate its size on its own.

I also had to use an `overflow: hidden` to prevent the scrollbar from appearing because doing a `right: -45px` will push the "right side" of the CSS Triangle box, so I can't use an `overflow: visible` anywhere too.

If I remove the fixed height, then I end up with `2.`

Is this possible to do without using an explicit height and other explicit measurements; how would you go about correctly vertically aligning it? If you have ideas using jQuery to grab widths and so forth, that's fine too - I've tagged it.

[image: CSS Triangle Image]

Comment: Are you trying to get a result that looks like the first image?

Comment: Yeah, basically.  In reality, the triangle should be overlapping the text on the right-side on the first image, and then there should just be a `margin: 5px 0px` or something on the triangle so that the triangle doesn't touch the border, but it still maintains its vertical alignment. There's a lot of extra padding around it because of the fixed `min-height`

Comment: You will need to use some scripting like javascript. The problem with this is your triangle is `position: absolute;`. The triangle will not be considered as a block element and there for the parent div will not expand to these elements.

Comment: @JoshPowell - that's not quite right... it's an `inline-block` element already.  I feel like you should be able to do this with just CSS.  You can change it to a `float: right`, and remove the `position: relative` and `position: absolute` - just tack on `margin-right: -45px` instead of `right: -45px`  The problem is clearing it to get a new block context without just inserting a `clear:both` `<p>` or something after it in the div.

Comment: What if the text is very long? Should it hover the arrow or something?

Comment: @Itay - not sure what you mean here.  If the text is very long and expands the container on its own, the arrow should just be in the vertical middle of the overall wrapper.

Comment: But in your picture it looks like the text will overlap the arrow

Comment: @Itay - doesn't really matter either way... it'd just be changing the `z-index`.

Comment: I made you a fiddle to show how they interact with the parent div. I am not 100% positive but I think you will need to use javascript to detect the size of content for the height on the div. http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/ECHJt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some jQuery to get rid of the hard-coded heights after assigning an arrowBox class to your div:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".arrowBox").each(function(){
    var border = $(this).height()/4;
    var right = "-"+(border-5)+"px";
    $(this).find(".arrow").css("border-width",border).css("right",right);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wzzRC/1/

That said, the difficulty with any pure CSS solution is that you can't specify border-width in %. So with pure CSS, use one of the other solutions to force the box to grow to accommodate the arrow. If you want a working arrow in smaller boxes, you need JS.

Comment: I like this idea; the only issue I'd bring up is that in order to create true responsiveness, it would have to listen to the window's size and recalculate each time it changes.  Not really a big deal though. I'll accept this for now.

Comment: Good point. You'd just want to take the code above and use jquery to bind it to a window change event. That's kind of beyond the scope of this question, but there are surely other questions out there about triggering a window size change event with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Set `position: relative;` on the white box container.

Set `position: absolute;` on the triangle with a top of 50% and `margin-top:` of half the height of the triangle.

That will make sure that the triangle is always in the middle.

Comment: Vertical alignment is hardly even an issue here.  The explicit measurement problems are still inherent.  As soon as you remove `min-height: 200px`, the container won't fill. See David's post.

Answer (score 1):

Change the triangle css to have:

```
top: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QuwEc/4/

Comment: Yeah, but then you remove `min-height: 200px;` and the container doesn't fill for the arrow.  That just fixes the vertical alignment - and it's an explicit measurement which I didn't really want.

Comment: @EricHotinger check again I forgot to save. The only explicit measurement is the triangle.

Comment: Not sure what version you're on, but `/4/` still has the same issue.

Comment: @EricHotinger what are you expecting, maybe I'm not fully understanding what you want: http://imgur.com/mXF25C7

Comment: The triangle shouldn't touch the border of the wrapper - in that picture, it's even being cut off.  The wrapper should expand to fit the entire triangle.

Comment: +1 Very good answer on having it centered! With a min-height you won't have to worry about anything that I was mentioning.

Comment: @EricHotinger http://jsfiddle.net/QuwEc/7/ is this close to what you are asking for? (minus horizontal positioning)

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.  If there is a small amount of text, the container will expand for the arrow.

Comment: @EricHotinger the only nice way of doing it is to use this answer + adding a min-height of the arrow height (2x border) on the div I can't think of any other way of doing this in pure css. Of course that means explicit min height of the triangle but I don't know the limitations you have on the heights of certain things. The absolute positioning means the div doesn't know the height of the triangle therefore cannot fallback to it when the text height is small.

Comment: Eric doesn't require pure CSS.